# can't change z index with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to change the Z index of an image according to the scroll position,currently in chrome (but it should be working on all broswers).
anyway, it's not working on chrome, unless I get into inspection mode and I don't understand why it's only working in inspection mode?

this is the script:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>700) { 
        document.getElementById("back-ground-image").style.zIndex = "-9";
        console.log("-9");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("back-ground-image").style.zIndex = "-19";
        console.log("-19");
    }
});
```

Comment: yes it does work for me and adds the zindex inline style property?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

What you need is `$(document)` not `$(window)`.

By default, you scroll the `$(document)`, not the `$(window)`.

However, when you open your Chrome DevTools, the `$(window)` is not being scrolled which is why your code works.

To fix the issue, change `$(window).scroll()` to `$(document).scroll()` and `$(window).scrollTop()` to `$(document).scrollTop()`

## Improvements

**1. Use jQuery functions**

Also, if you're already using jQuery, why not use [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$("#back-ground-image").css('zIndex', '-9')
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("back-ground-image").style.zIndex = "-9";
```

**2. Use DRY code**

[(Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/dry-code-vs-wet-code-89xjwv11w)

If you follow recommendation #1, why not set `$("#back-ground-image")` to a variable instead of repeating it twice.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
        $bkImg = $("#back-ground-image");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700) {
        $bkImg.css('zIndex', '-9');
        console.log("-9");
    } else {
        $bkImg.css('zIndex', '-19');
        console.log("-19");
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you could use:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
        background = document.getElementById("back-ground-image");
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>700) { 
        background.style.zIndex = "-9";
        console.log("-9");
    } else {
        background.style.zIndex = "-19";
        console.log("-19");
    }
});
```